# How to run Builded vue js project in browser without server on locall machin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**I use 'vue-cli**'. **I ran 'npm run build' command** to get build version of the project . Due to this, automatically in 'dist' folder was created 'index.html'. Look at image:

[image]

I tried to run **index.html file** in browser, but it **doesn't work**. Massage form console in browser:

[image]

The content of my Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>cv</title>
    <style type=text/css>
       html, body{
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
       }</style>
    <link href='/static/css/app.b3ceb6191281c6a4dd333aa0b8aed7cd.css' rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=app>
    </div>

    <script type=text/javascript src='/static/js/manifest.488e7f096afe65619705.js'></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src='/static/js/vendor.fa2e9b388f427a714cca.js'></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src='/static/js/app.d3d1742ab1cad95402a6.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**What I have to do to run it in the browser without server using**?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want use server, you have to change all source links to

```
='./static/
```

or

```
='static/
```

1st variant is preferred

Comment: I think your advice is correct. I used './static/'. It helped me to solve problems with connected to 'index.html' files. But after that I'v got another issue (messeg from console) with images in my code. As I understand all they have the same problem with references. So why command 'npm run build' in 'build' project creates wrong references and how to correct that?

Comment: I use require() function to get images in my project. Example from my code: <img class="APP-HEADER-IMG" :src='require("./assets/img/AppHeader.png")' alt="fon" @load="ShowNameAndSwitchersOnPage">. Maybe problem is here...

Comment: Why did u do so? U use vue-cli, and there is mechanism to make correct urls for build vershion with url-loader. Can u remove require for images?

Comment: I have some components with images inside. For example: <template> <div><img src='...' alt='...'></div></template>.  I use 'v-bind' to transfer 'src' string to them from outside. Project compiles fine with 'npm run dev' command, when I do that without require(). BUT browser doesn't show them when i don't use v-bind:my-src=" require('./sameFile.aaa')"  to transfer 'src' string to image.

Comment: I didn't have such problems when I was using  framework 'Laravel'. So I see this sort of problem at first working with vue-cli (wabpack).

Comment: As decision u can replace img to div with background style

Comment: This is the massage of 'npm run build' command: 'Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server. Opening index.html over file:// won't work.' Maybe there is a way to change same settings in wabpack file, that will help to solve the problem with references in build project?